# Почему не находит изображение?

Tags: python, pygame

Почему программа не находит изображение если папка находится в той же директории что и главный файл?

```
surf = pygame.image.load('\image\Character\Select\Josuke.png')
surf = pygame.transform.scale(rect, (240,130))
rect = surf.get_rect(bottomright=(100,1100))
sc.blit(surf, rect)
```

Answer (score 2):

Так вы же перетираете значение загруженного в `surf` изображения следующей же строкой кода:

```
surf = pygame.image.load('\image\Character\Select\Josuke.png')  
# сейчас в surf находится изображение

surf = pygame.transform.scale(rect, (240,130)) 
# изображение потеряно, теперь в surf трансформированный rect
```